# How to pass a HTML control to another javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I want to pass HTML control to another function inside JavaScript. I am calling a modal popup which has a input control and a save button.

The function in which i am calling the modal popup has entire `GridView` row as a parameter. I want to pass this to another javascript function which will be called on the button click inside of modal dialog.

I tried as below but it passes a string variable.

```
function ShowDialogPeoplePicker(id, requestType, cntrl) {

    var row = cntrl.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
    var Approvers = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

    if (requestType == "AddApprovers") {
        $('#btnAddApprover').removeAttr('onclick');
        $('#btnAddApprover').attr('onClick', 'if (!setApprovers(\''  +cntrl + '\')) return false;');
    }
}
```

The below function will be called on a button click and will set the values inside `GridView` row.

```
function setApprovers(cntrl)
{
    var usernames= $("#hdnApproversName_CTO").val();
    var row = cntrl.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
    row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = usernames;

    $("#overlayTasks").hide();
    $("#dialogTasks").hide();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: $(cntrl) is your html element then row would be $(cntrl).parent().parent(). Although i don't see why it wouldn't work like your wrote it. And avoid mixing js and jquery. Stick to one to make it more clear for everyone including yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attaching your click handler like this:

```
$('#btnAddApprover').attr('onClick', 'if (!setApprovers(\''  +cntrl + '\')) return false;');
```

Try this instead:

```
$('#btnAddApprover').on('click', function() {
    setApprovers(cntrl);
});
```

If you need to remove previously added event listeners, you can do that with:

```
$('#btnAddApprover').off('click');
```

Or if you want to attach the listener to listen just one time in the first place, you can use:

```
$('#btnAddApprover').one('click', function() {
    setApprovers(cntrl);
});
```

(with `one` instead of `on`). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#btnAddApprover').attr('onClick', 'if (!setApprovers(\''  +cntrl + '\')) return false;');
```

use

```
$('#btnAddApprover').click(function() {
  return setApprovers(cntrl);
}
```